# Chamisha Veshishim Umatayim - mi yodeya?

Tags: number, mi-yodeya-series

### Who knows two hundred sixty-five?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible.*

*At some point between twenty-four hours and a few days from now, I will:*

- *Vote up all interesting, relevant answers.*
- *Accept what I consider the "best" answer.*
- *Move on to the next number.*

*Lazy gematria for today is: [סהר](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A1%D7%94%D7%A8).*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

מודים אנחנו לך = 265 this is the unlazy one;)

Comment: C8^) ..........

Answer (score 4):

Shes was 105 years old when Enosh was born. וַיְחִי-שֵׁת חָמֵשׁ שָׁנִים וּמְאַת שָׁנָה וַיּוֹלֶד אֶת-אֱנוֹשׁ.

Enosh was 90 years old when Keinon was born. וַיְחִי אֱנוֹשׁ תִּשְׁעִים שָׁנָה וַיּוֹלֶד אֶת-קֵינָן.

Keinon was 70 years old when Mahalalel was born. וַיְחִי קֵינָן שִׁבְעִים שָׁנָה וַיּוֹלֶד אֶת-מַהֲלַלְאֵל.

Based on this Shes was 265 years old when Mahalalel was born.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.jewishtucson.org/page.aspx?id=216483

> A well-trained scribe, who has to say each word aloud before writing
>   it, can finish a Torah in about **265** days of seven to eight hours
>   of penning per day.

Answer (score 1):

In a leap year, *Yom Yerushalayim* is the 265th day in the year if *Heshvan* is whole (has 30 days) and *Kislev* is *Haser* (has 29 days) or vice versa:

*Tishrei* - 30 days each
*Heshvan*, *Kislev* - 59 days together
*Tevet* - 29 days
*Shvat* - 30 days
*Adar A* - 29 days
*Adar B* - 30 days
*Nisan* - 30 days
*Iyar* - 28 days (*Yom Yerushalayim* is on the 28th day of *Iyar*)